# How to print JMS To Http response in WSO2ESB Proxy

Tags: wso2-esb

I have an Apache MQ configured with wso2esb4.9.0, Proxy-A accepts http requests and puts the request payload on a Queue (Queue-1). Proxy-B listening to Queue-1 takes the payload and calls an HTTP EndPoint [say, EndPoint-1] with the payload parameters received from the Queue-1. I am trying to print the HTTPResponse from EndPoint-1 which is throwing errors. Please find the two proxies that I have created and please let me know if there is anything missing, how I can make it print response from the EndPoint-1. I invoke Proxy-A as HttpPost with a payload {"test":["test","test"]} ; I am just trying to to log the response coming back from backend to the Proxy-B

Thanks in advance...

[expected flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjOWt.png)

Proxy-A ::

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="Proxy-A"
           transports="http"
           statistics="disable"
           trace="disable"
           startOnLoad="true">
       <target>
          <inSequence>
             <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
             <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="jms:/InQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <send/>
          </outSequence>
       </target>
       <description/>
    </proxy>
```

Proxy-B ::

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ProfileServiceInvokeProxy"
       transports="jms http https"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="enable">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
 <!-- property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/> -->
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/testResponse"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
<outSequence>
<send/>
</outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">BensInQueue</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
         <default>application/json</default>
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>
```

I see the following exception after updating the Proxy-B

Exception Details -

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2015-10-26 13:34:53,678]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/testResponse, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:f171620e-12d5-4053-83b5-8dac3c05643c, Direction: request, Payload: {"ids":["abc123"]} {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2015-10-26 13:34:53,865] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Runtime error occurred while mediating the message {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:119)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>` from the proxy service B and try this.

Above property Set to ‘true’ on a proxy service to indicate that no response message is expected for the dispatched  message from the ESB. In other words the ESB will do an out-only invocation with such messages. Please refer to the [Official Document.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-OUT_ONLY)

Comment: why are you using a call mediator here ? Using call mediator take response into the next mediator (in-sequence) So thats why you may not get the response to the out-sequence. You can simply use send mediator to send message and bring response to the out sequence.

Comment: Krishan, i used send and call both , when pasted here i happen to post this one...i am parallely trying to get this going, if you have ever tried such scenario could you try replicating (of course if your time permits); if I myself got it today I will post the answer!

Comment: Please see the updated proxy and the exception I am getting for your reference

Comment: can you pls state exact requirement? i am not clear what you going to do. its better u can explain process in breaf

Comment: I am trying to access a message from queue and use the message to call a service and log the response...

Answer (score 0):

I have used MessageProcessors and the "receive sequences" from WSO2ESB4.9 to address this scenario